# Command to list all media entities in console?

Tags: 8, console

I have an issue in my site which is not allowing me to visit the `/en/admin/content/media` page.

I'm looking for an approach to list and delete media entities on the command line.

When I run `drupal debug:entity media` I get an error:

```
[ERROR] <em class="placeholder">Notice</em>: Undefined index: media in <em                                     
         class="placeholder">Drupal\Console\Command\Debug\EntityCommand-&gt;execute()</em> (line <em            
         class="placeholder">79</em> of <em                                                                     
         class="placeholder">/home/ubuntu/site/vendor/drupal/console/src/Command/Debug/EntityCommand.php</em> 
         ). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Console\Command\Debug\EntityCommand-&gt;execute(Object, Object)       
         (Line: 255)                                                                                            
         Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command-&gt;run(Object, Object) (Line: 971)                          
         Symfony\Component\Console\Application-&gt;doRunCommand(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 248)             
         Symfony\Component\Console\Application-&gt;doRun(Object, Object) (Line: 185)                            
         Drupal\Console\Core\Application-&gt;doRun(Object, Object) (Line: 64)                                   
         Drupal\Console\Application-&gt;doRun(Object, Object) (Line: 148)                                       
         Symfony\Component\Console\Application-&gt;run() (Line: 89)                                             
         require(&#039;/home/ubuntu/site/vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal.php&#039;) (Line: 4)                
         </pre>
```

The [docs](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/debug-entity.html) of this command is also really uninformative.

What's the best approach to list and delete media entities on the command line?

Comment: If you want to do it with code try this `$media_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
    ->execute();
  foreach ($media_ids as $id => $media_id){
    $media = Media::load($media_id);
    $media->delete();
  }`

Answer (score -1):

If you use Drush, you can try drush sql-query like this : 
 `drush sql-query "Delete from name_table weher condition"`